# Get value for a key fron non-default bucket in couchbase

Tags: memcached, couchbase

I would like to get an object from couchbase memcached bucket that is not the *default*, using memcached interface (or any other method).

Right now to get data from the default bucket I just do:

```
echo "get someKey" | nc couchbase.server 11211
```

But how to retrieve data from different bucket? Memcached doesn't have a notion of buckets (at least I couldn't find any info about that).

Or if that way is not possible can I use a different interface to retrieve the data from the shell (using nc or curl)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but you will need to use "client-side moxi"

You can find more information about it here

http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/Concepts/bp-deployment-strategies.html

Alternatively you can install the Couchbase C SDK and use "cbc cat" which is bucket-aware.

Answer (score 0):

the C Couchbase SDK comes with a command line tool called `cbc` that can be used to retrieve documents from any bucket in a Couchbase cluster, `cbc cat`.

see the [documentation on how to install and use cbc](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/sdk/webui-cli-access.html)